# CSS change image in Style sheet where original image was not using stylesheet

Tags: css, image, stylesheet

I am trying to overwrite a style that is in a master page with one on the local page (I can not edit the master page).  NOTE I had to remove parts of the tags in my code so they showed up in comments

I have a tag in a master page that looks like this:

```
<img class="paddingT5" src="~/Content/themes/mobius/img/smallMobiusLogo.png" />
```

With the tag in a separate stylesheet defined like this:

```
.paddingT5 {
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

I know I can write a style on the local page that will overwrite the style in the master page (already done it with page background color.

```
.paddingT5 {
   padding-top: 5px;
   background-image: url("~/Areas/MO/Views/SRT/TazDizzyImage.jpg");   
}
```

If I change the padding in the above it works, but the image will not change.

Either I have the wrong CSS style, or I just can not do this.

Comment: You want to change the src ? bakcground-image on img element ?

Comment: @Danko based on reading that I think that is exactly what he wants to do. So he needs to use JS to do it... CSS doesn't have the ability to replace a src and src has more power than CSS in this case. Think of it as an inline style that can't be overridden by pure CSS

Comment: I know the URL is correct, I placed an image tag on the page with the same URL and it works.   When I Try to use the background-image (also tried just background)  The image wont change, and even if the image URL was wrong the background image should show the image not found box instead of the image itself

Comment: Ok, got the image to show up, but it is on top of (or behind) original image (they are both .pngs) so the old image is not being replaced.  Assuming because the original image was hardcded and not in a style sheet.

Comment: One more thing I found (dont thing related to this) but if I type in ONE path (where other items exist in the project) the image shows up, but if I type in a path that is new and no images exist, it can not find the image???   I am writing in VS 2013 and an Angular JS site.

Is there some setting where it wont let me put images in a certain director or something?